# Unable to deserialize a field when using FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES

Tags: gson

I am using gson for deserialization. I have a field with the name "listName" it has @Expose annotation.

When I set FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES in GsonBuilder and create Gson object using this GsonBuilder, then  that field is not getting deserialized.

When I do not use FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES then that field is getting serialized.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json field name should be "list_name" and your pojo object would have the field listName, when you are using that FieldNamingPolicy.

JSON:

```
{
    "list_name": ""
}
```

POJO CLASS:

```
class POJO 
{
    String listName;
}
```

IF, when you do not use FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES and that field IS getting deserialized [sic]... then my guess is that your json field name is also "listName".